# Method definition - Volume of a pyramid - Returning method call to another method

Tags: java, methods, return

I can't figure out what's happening to cause the errors that I'm receiving to return the pyramidVolume that I'm trying to call.  This problem comes from zyBooks and I can only edit the class CalcPyramidVolume.  Here is my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CalcPyramidVolume {
   double calcPyramidVolume(double baseLength, double baseWidth, double baseHeight);
   double baseArea;
   double pyramidVolume;
   
   baseArea = baseLength * baseWidth;
   pyramidVolume = baseArea * baseHeight * (1.0/3.0);
   
   return pyramidVolume;

   public static void main (String [] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      double userLength;
      double userWidth;
      double userHeight;

      userLength = scnr.nextDouble();
      userWidth = scnr.nextDouble();
      userHeight = scnr.nextDouble();

      System.out.println("Volume: " + pyramidVolume(userLength, userWidth, userHeight));
   }
}
```

So I'm trying to pass the arguments in the output statement to the parameters of the calcPyramidVolume method.
I get the following error messages from the compiler.

```
CalcPyramidVolume.java:8: error: <identifier> expected
   baseArea = baseLength * baseWidth;
           ^
CalcPyramidVolume.java:9: error: <identifier> expected
   pyramidVolume = baseArea * baseHeight * (1.0/3.0);
                ^
CalcPyramidVolume.java:11: error: illegal start of type
   return pyramidVolume;
   ^
CalcPyramidVolume.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
   return pyramidVolume;
                       ^
4 errors
```

I'm not sure what is meant by identifier expected, I've triple-checked the spelling and declarations of my variables.

Comment: Remove the semicolon after your method declaration, replace it with curly brackets, and then stick everything below it up until the main method inside those curly brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it!   I'm only able to change what's above the main() method. After reviewing my text material more thoroughly, I seen that I needed to add a public class static double pyramidVolume. I've listed my correction to only the updated class below, since the rest is the same.

```
public class CalcPyramidVolume {

   public static double pyramidVolume(double userLength, double userWidth, double userHeight) {
   double baseArea;  //added public static class with same variables as in the main method
   
   baseArea = userLength * userWidth;
   double pyramidVolume = baseArea * userHeight * (1.0/3.0);  //added double type to pyramidVolume since it's not declared inside the braces
   
   return pyramidVolume;
   }
```